# How to use alternative combined fragments in Visio 2007?

Tags: uml, sequence, diagram, visio

I have been spending looking for how to use alternative combined fragments in Visio 2007 for UML sequence diagram, but it seems like there is no notation to create this if-then-else statement.

(like the following in visual-paradigm: http://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/?p=788)

Is alternatives supported by Visio 2007? (otherwise, how do we create if-then-else block in Visio?)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found solution!

Visio uses UML 2.2 and hence does not have alt. box.

However, there are plugins for Visio all versions here: http://softwarestencils.com/uml/index.html
There are alt. box shapes included.